# How to create object based off .txt file information and assign to an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry, java.util.scanner

GeometricObjectsData.txt:

```
CIRCLE, 1, blue, true
RECTANGLE, 1, 2, blue, true
RECTANGLE, 10, 2, red, true
CIRCLE, 2, green
RECTANGLE
CIRCLE
```

I'm not sure how I add the information from the .txt file to an object Circle() or Rectangle() and then add it to an ArrayList so I can compare the largest object based off Area.

I can post the other classes if needed, but I am just stuck on the main method where I create an object based off the information in the text file.

EDIT:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(
                "C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/GeometricObjectsData.txt"));

        ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(", ");
            if (tokens[0].equals("CIRCLE")) {
                Circle c = new Circle();
                float radius = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
                c.setRadius(radius);
                String color = String.valueOf(tokens[2]);
                c.setColor(color);
                Boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(tokens[3]);
                c.setFilled(filled);
                c.getArea();
                list.add(c);
                System.out.println(c.toString());
            } else if (tokens[0].equals("RECTANGLE")) {
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                float height = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                r.setHeight(height);
                float width = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                r.setWidth(width);
                String color = String.valueOf(tokens[3]);
                r.setColor(color);
                Boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(tokens[4]);
                r.setFilled(filled);
                r.getArea();
                list.add(r);
                System.out.println(r.toString());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExecption after I changed the code to that. I think it stops when it hits the 4th line where it doesn't have the 4th token indicating if it is filled/not filled. How do I fix that?

Comment: Sorry I changed it a bit, this is the part I don't understand. How do I take that information from the .txt file and create a new Circle() or new Rectangle() object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the info you need for creating these shapes are available on Oracle's website.

Circles: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Circle.html

Rectangles: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

I'm not sure exactly what the data in your txt file represents, but assuming the number for the circles is the radius and the two numbers for the rectangles are its width and height, you would want something like:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/GeometricObjectsData.txt"));

    // you read each line at a time, so better to have hasNextLine instead
    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        String[] tokens = line.split(", ");
        if (tokens[0].equals("Circle"){
            Circle c = new Circle();
            float radius = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            c.setRadius(radius);

            // do what you wish with circle
        }
        else if (tokens[0].equals("Rectangle"){
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            int height = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            int width = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            r.setSize(width,height);

            // do what you wish with rectangle
        }

    }
```

As for the other information provided on the txt file, you will need to explain what the `true` means. Neither the circle nor rectangle classes have methods involving color, so if you plan to draw them, on a canvas, then you will need to look up the methods for a canvas pertaining to filling in colors.

Comment: Sorry it's Circle - radius, color, filled and Rectangle - height, width, color, filled.

Comment: Just swapped the values for the rectangle width and height. This is really the most you can do if it comes to just setting the properties of either a rectangle or circle object.

Comment: For the colors, you can't actually can't get the color from them this way. They would need to be in hexidecimal format to actually read them. So in the text file, instead of `blue`, you would have 0x0000FF (since blue is this in hex). From here you can use the `decode` method to parse the hex color into a long type. Mor einfo on the method: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/long_decode.htm

Comment: I'm not actually doing anything with the color and whether or not it's a filled shape other then displaying the information. I'm just trying to compare the Areas of the objects and grab the position of the object with the largest area in the array list.

Comment: Also after I changed the code it keeps saying ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to add the objects to the arraylist

Comment: So lets say you had the methods for getting the area of either the circle or the rectangle (simple enough). Now instead of having an ArrayList of geometric objects, you could instead save the areas in an array of double that you would keep adding to every time you read a new line and calculated the area for the shape. From here you can sort it with `Collections.sort(AreaArrayList)` and the last element in the array will be the largest area.

Comment: I have classes that compute the Area for the rectangle and circle, after I do .getArea what would I type to add the area only to a different arraylist? Also when the while loop gets to the 4th line where it doesn't have all of the parameteres it gives an arrayindexoutofboundsexception error, how do I prevent that? Do I use a try/catch?

Comment: You could try that. Why are those lines included in your code anyway without those parameters? So for adding doubles to an ArrayList, you would need something like `ArrayList<Double> areas = new ArrayList<>();` and in your loop have `areas.add(c);` for circle and `areas.add(r)` for rectangle.

Comment: http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~matos/notes/cis-265/2014-fall/homework/cis265-fall2014-hw03.pdf This is a link to the assignment, I re-read it and it says that I need to get the areas from the ArrayList<GeometricObjects> and because in the GeometricObject class I have there are default values that are suppose to be assigned such as white and false, 1 width, 1 height, 1 radius but they are not being assigned to the new objects

Comment: Ah, didn't know `GeometricObject` was a class. I don't think I should really help from this point since I feel like I would be kinda doing your HW for you. Everything you need is actually on that sheet. Good luck!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. Could you tell me why when the new objects are created that they don't get the default values if they don't have a parameter in the .txt file?

Comment: It's because for those two lines where there aren't any parameters, you're trying to get those nonexistent parameters with `tokens[1]; tokens[2]; tokens[3]; etc..` when those lines only provide the type of object (circle/rectangle).

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Pi Joules answer, you should probably make sure you are accounting for case in your text file:

```
if (tokens[0].equals("CIRCLE")){
```

Or better yet:

`if (tokens[0].toUpperCase().equals("CIRCLE")){`

Or even better yet:

`if (tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Circle")){`

Comment: Thanks I forgot about this.